# Javascript redirect does not work

Tags: javascript, frames

The following codes displays the alert, but does not take me to the requested page.

```
function redirect() {
    alert('runs');
    parent.main.document.location = "url.php";
}
```

I'm using frames, I want the page to load into the frame named 'main'. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you sure that parent is the actual 'window' you are trying to redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
function redirect() {
    alert('runs');
    window.location = "url.php";
}
```

And for frames you can use it like this:

```
top.frames["main"].location.href="url.php";
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Please Use window.location.href or location.href instead of document.location.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes in JavaScript, you may want to redirect a user to another URL. This is often done setting the window.location properly like so:
window.location = "http://google.com/';
However, Safari and IE 5.2 for Mac (at least on OSX) behave a little differently than browsers on the PC. I put together this basic test page in order to see which scenarios work and which don't.

[refer this link for the code](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/windowlocation)

Tests 2, 4 and 5 work but 1 and 3 don't. And you can probably see why. In 1 and 3, we set the window.location to a new URL. This would normally redirect the user to the new page. But after the onclick event, it runs the URL contained in the href and overrides the redirect. In this case, the # keeps the page from redirecting altogether. By putting return false; we stop the href from being processed altogether.